# Docker not using postgres version specified in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker

Docker is not using postgres version specified in docker compose. I have this:

```
activities-db:
    container_name: activitiesdb
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_DB_NAME=activitiesdb
    ports:
        - '5433:5432'
    volumes: 
        - db_activities:/var/lib/postgresql@15/data
    networks:
      - app-network
```

and still when i execute this container it shows this:
`# psql -U postgres psql (16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1)) Type "help" for help.`

The command I use to execute the container is `Docker compose exec activities-db sh`. After that, I’m running psql -U postgres inside the container.

Comment: Which command did you use to execute the container?Include it in the question.

Comment: Your example need to be more complete.  You use network and volume, but don't declare them, nor the version of the docker-compose file. Are you executing `psql` from within the container?  Show the `docker exec` (or whatever you did)

Comment: If you're running `psql -h localhost -p 5433` from the host (which I'd recommend over `docker exec`) then that diagnostic message has the version of the `psql` client tool and not necessarily the remote database.

Comment: @jjanes I already wrote what I did.